# How to link to next date (day/month) with date in url?

Tags: date, links, next-prev

When displaying entries by date: /blog/2013/09/12 (day) or /blog/2013/09 (month),

1. How can i get the link to the next/previous day or month?
2. More important, when using the [channel calendar](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/calendar.html#day-path) tag, using the day-path variable in the calendar will show links for days that have entries. When visiting such a link (/blog/2013/09/12), how can i link on that page to the next date **that does have entries** ?